# create restapi with token authentication

Tags: java, rest, authentication, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to create RestApi first time. Looking for assistance after reading text present online.

My requirement is, I want to create an rest api which will be having username and password. Password will be in encrypted format. So when this api client will request to a web server, that password will be decrypted first on server side and then if the user name and password authenticates then it will send back a temporary token with expiry date. Then again that token will be used in rest api to request data from the web server in xml format.

How can we achieve this ?

And I also want to understand if we encrypt a password in client server then how its get decrypts on web server side. Is the same instance travels from client to web server side while making request ?

Second, The data which I'm trying to consume from web server are the email ids of users which registers on website. My question, If user is getting registered on website then website must be storing those email ids somewhere like in database right ? And my restApi will be accessing the code on web-server side  which is responsible to get email ids from database in xml format. Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't concern yourself directly with encrypting details client-side and decrypting them server-side.  If you are using TLS/HTTPS (which you **should be**) then all is well, everything is already encrypted.

The token generation is slightly more difficult but still easy enough.  A commonly used and simple to implement method is to use JWT tokens.  The general idea is that you create a JSON object like the following:

```
{ "userID": "FC5A47CC", "expiry": "12/10/2017" }
```

And then run it through an HMAC using a key only your server knows.  You append the result of the HMAC to the JSON object using base64 encoding and then send this to your client after they have logged in.

Using this method, authentication is very fast, as your web server won't need to make any requests to your database server to determine if the token is valid.  You can read more about JWT [here](https://jwt.io/).  I've answered a similar question in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971800/generating-a-secure-cookie-token-to-store-persistently/45971915#45971915).

As your question asks, these userIDs will obviously need to be stored in your database.

Comment: You are saying HTTPS automatically takes care about user name and password we are passing into restapi url. I dont need to encrypt them further, HTTPS keep them safe while making request via internet. Is it really so ?

Comment: @LearnJava Yes, that is the whole point of HTTPS.  Arguably it isn't a good idea to pass the username and password in a URL since these could appear in server logs etc.  But they are still encrypted and unreadable in transit.

Comment: So what will be an best approach if want to pass my user name and password in url ? Like you said its not a good idea..!

Comment: @LearnJava Sending them as the body of a POST request over HTTPS would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you please show me any example, where we are passing POST request over HTTPS in url ?

Comment: @LearnJava That isn't really in scope for your question and is a trivial thing to accomplish.  You'll be able to Google search easily to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want client app to consume resources on behalf of user. I propose OAuth 2.0, which provides mechanism, which you have described to access protected resources without storing passwords. Client app requests a username and password from the user (for example by using a login form) and then send that credentials to the server. Upon receipt and validation server returns token to the client. Client stores token locally and discards username and password. All subsequent request are authorized by token, which can be accomplished using a custom HTTP header, for example X-Auth-Token. Server can optionally provide a refresh token along with the access token, which is used by client to obtain new access token, once current expires. HTTPS/SSL technology is required by OAuth 2.0, so data over wire will be encrypted.

There are 4 roles defined by OAuth 2.0 :

1) Authorization Server — does identity verification and grants token to the client app. 
2) Resource Server — Server which hosts actual protected user resource.
3) Resource Owner — User willing to provide access to his protected resource.
4) Client — application that gets access to a user’s resources.

You can use [Spring Security OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) framework to implement this requirement.